# DTS file explanation - aliases

Tags: operating-system, embedded, embedded-linux, systems-programming, device-tree

I am trying to understand the following snippet from a DTS file.

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    model = "MPC8313ERDB";
    compatible = "MPC8313ERDB", "MPC831xRDB", "MPC83xxRDB";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;

    aliases {
        ethernet0 = &enet0;
        serial0 = &serial0;
        serial1 = &serial1;
        pci0 = &pci0;
    };
```

What does the aliases part does?
My understanding is as follows.
For ethernet0, we can use enet0.
But why serial0=&serial0?
and serial1 = &serial1
Can anyone brief please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the **`aliases`** section of a DTS, we see entries of the format

> **`property = &label;`**

Each of the entries consists of :
a. `property` -- A new **property** defined here.
b. `&label` -- **Complete DTS path** to the `node` referenced by the `label`.

It basically assigns the value of **b** to **a**. Henceforth, the long-name to the node identified by the `label` can be accessed using the shorthand `property`.

Note that the RHS of this assignment is using `label`s and **NOT** the short-names of the individual nodes. Just like a `label` in C code refers to an instruction on the line where it is defined, a `label` in DTS refers to the individual node (using its complete long path) that is defined on that line.

For example, considering the following DTS,
[lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts)

whose `aliases` section consists of the following :

```
 20         aliases {
 21                 ethernet0 = &enet0;
 22                 ethernet1 = &enet1;
 23                 serial0 = &serial0;
 24                 serial1 = &serial1;
 25                 pci0 = &pci0;
 26         };
```

The newly defined properties (LHS)

- `ethernet0`
- `ethernet1`
- `serial0`
- `serial1`
- `pci0`

refer to the corresponding labels (RHS)

- [`enet0`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts#L192)
- [`enet1`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts#L229)
- [`serial0`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts#L261)
- [`serial1`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts#L271)
- [`pci0`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts#L333)

For example, the property **`ethernet0`** is now set to **`"/soc8313@e0000000/ethernet@24000"`** i.e. the node defined on [the line where the label `enet0` is defined](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/dts/mpc8313erdb.dts#L192).

---

**UPDATE** :

1. Why are aliases defined ONLY for `ethernet0`, `serial0` ... ?

   - Further down the line, the developer intends to access these nodes in the kernel source code. Once an **alias** is defined in the DTS, a **handle to the node it is referring to** is obtained by simply searching for it in the `aliases` section rather than searching for it in the entire DTS.

     Source: The function **[find_node_by_alias()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/ops.h#L171)** in the Linux kernel source.
2. Why `pci0` node in **NOT** under the `soc8313` node?

   - On MPC8313, the **PCI** and **DMA** blocks are interfaced via the IO-Sequencer(IOS). Hence the special treatment as compared to the other blocks (ethernet, I2C, UART) that are connected directly to the system bus.

Comment: Thank you so much TheCodeArtist for rescuing me again. Now I understand they are more like the aliases we set in unix shell to refer to complete path. mpc8313erdb.dts is the exact dts file I am investigating. You are my saviour.  
Why are we defining aliases only for         ethernet0 = &enet0;
        serial0 = &serial0;
        serial1 = &serial1;
        pci0 = &pci0;
And pci0 is not under soc.

Comment: In my dts file pic0 is set to "/pci@e0008500" ?
What is the need to do this?

Comment: I have updated the answer with details. While i am unable to find the exact location where `pci0` is referenced in code i did find one for `ethernet0` **[here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/cuboot-83xx.c#L27)**. Studying that function's internals should help you understand and appreciate the beauty of device-tree.

Comment: Holy cow.. TheCodeArtist you just know everything. Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you find the function using the aliases? " find_node_by_alias()" and the node where "ethernet0" is referenced? Grepped "ethernet0"? Can you kindly share? I would like to know.
And where do you get the explanation of the DTS file. I am trying to reverse engineer the whole file. I am referring to http://devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Usage and https://www.power.org/documentation/epapr-version-1-1/
Can you kindly share your resources?

Comment: Yup, you are **absolutely** right - grep-ing `ethernet0` inside `arch/powerpc` and following the chain of function calls [all the way down](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/powerpc/boot/ops.h#L171). Here is a **[series of articles](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1)** explaining the basics of device-tree.

Comment: Thank you so much friend. You are amazing. Thanks for sharing the technique and the link.